# Function parameter type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function to loop over an Array and look for a number.

```js
function search(arr, num) { }
```

This function takes an **Array** and an **Integer** as the input. But I want the parameters to be of their respective types, is there any way I can set the type of the parameters.

Comment: Javascript doesn't support static types, that's why TypeScript was born.

Comment: Sidenote: Though it doesn't prevent you from passing a different type you can add [JSDoc comments](https://jsdoc.app/index.html) for better autocomplete, which get picked up by most editors.

Comment: You can add assertions like `function search(arr, num) { if (!Array.isArray(arr)) throw new Error('Wrong type'); if (!typeof num !== 'number')) throw new Error('Wrong type'); }`

Comment: for checking types in javascript please refer [javascript typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: @Reyno This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot. I was having trouble with auto-completion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to enforce an specific data type you need to explicitly write that

```
/**
 * looks for an specific item of the list.
 *
 * @param {Array<string>} data Array to search from.
 * @param {number} num Number of where to find bla bla.
 * @throws {TypeError} in case data or num do not have the expected type
 * @returns {string} item found.
 */
export function search(data, num) {
    if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
        throw new TypeError("data should be an array");
    }

    if (typeof num !== "number") {
        throw new TypeError("num should be a number");
    }

    return data[num];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fun fact: `typeof NaN` is also `number`, so you need to also account for that for best behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a loosely typed language, there's no way to say *declaratively* that `arr` should be an array and `num` should be a number other than documentation (for instance, [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/index.html)). That would look like this:

```
/**
 * Searches (insert fuller description here).
 *
 * @param   {number[]} arr The array to search through.
 * @param   {number}   num The number to (use? search for?)
 * @returns (you can use the same {syntax} to say what the return type is)
 */
function search(arr, num) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
        throw new Error(`'arr' argument must be an array`);
    }
    if (typeof num !== "number"/* Or use `Number.isInteger(num)` for an integer check [it includes the typecheck]*/) {
        throw new Error(`'num' argument must be a number`);
    }
    // ...do the work...
}
```

You *could* check at runtime. That would look something like this:

```
function search(arr, num) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
        throw new Error(`'arr' argument must be an array`);
    }
    if (typeof num !== "number"/* && perhaps a check for int if that part is really important*/) {
        throw new Error(`'num' argument must be a number`);
    }
    // ...do the work...
}
```

There's a language built on top of JavaScript called [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), which adds a static type system. It's then compiled to JavaScript for use with the browser, Node.js, etc. You may want to look into using that, if static typing is important for what you're doing.

In TypeScript, you'd do it like this (if you want the array to be an array of numbers):

```
function search(arr: number[], num: number) {
    // ...
}
```

That doesn't require an *integer*, all JavaScript numbers are IEEE-754 floating point or `BigInt`s.

Comment: I found your answer extremely helpful and it was really well written, helped me a lot.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors

Comment: @Ernesto - ??? Is that a **really** subtle way of suggesting adding a `@throws` annotation?

Answer (score -3):

javascript is a loosely type language. beacuse of it there are no types, you can actively check if the given parameter is array by .isArray() and  .isInteger(), this both methods will return the booleen.

the answer given by pravat work but it can be devasting as they will not only set the type its will set its default value, in case if you didn't send the value of num then function will asume its 10 and start to work, which can be pain in debuging if you need strict type please look into typescript.

Comment: _"beacuse of it there are no types"_ That's wrong. There are types in JavaScript